# Wpf app without any xaml design views

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an app and have found that in 90% of the pages and windows there is no designer.

in some cases a xaml page is present but empty with a content presenter. eventually i find my way to a cs file that the content presenter is bound to and guess my way around until i find where the code is i need to work on.

question is, is this common in industry? as the last place i worked was all mvvm with design views and code was in the view model.

any clarification at all as to why someone would program this way?

Comment: To generate the views dynamically during run time!

Comment: "why someone would program this way?" How should we know that?

Comment: @Clemens maybe someone whos been around a while could say "it was done this way before mvvm" or "this is what we did before mvvm took off because...."

Comment: I turned the design view off anyway after a very short time of getting used to WPF. It's requiring ugly workarounds like having a designer specific conditional in the `Loaded` event handler, designer based views tend to suck when it comes to resize behavior, it slows VS down ... I just write my view xaml directly into the `DataTemplate` in some resource dictionary instead of redirecting from the `DataTemplate` to some `UserControl`. Have yet to find a real downside to that approach. Not having the designer doesn't count as downside for me.

Comment: @grek40 thanks for the answer, seems this has been done here too. the buttons are defined in the resource dictionary, i find this difficult to navigate and find things. I personally prefer having a view, viewmodel and also a designer view model so i dont need to run the app to see how its going to look. but yeah doesnt help for dynamic resizing ect